# Browse JavaScript using tags in Atom

Tags: atom-editor

In the Atom editor, I cannot browse the JavaScript code a la `vim+ctags`.

I have tried the `atom-ctags` plugin, but it didn't work. Is there any other plugin?

How can I do it?

ok.

```
 $cd <src-dir>
```

<.ctags> is present in it.

```
$atom . 

<opens the editor, 0.187 release> <atom-ctags is installed in it>
```

In .ctags, following tag is present: `calcSplices .../binding/src/array-change-records.js /calcSplices/;" f lineno:255 type:Array function(?, number, number, Array[?], number, number)`

I open the js file in the atom editor.

I go to 'calcSplices' function usage.

Right-click and click go-to-declaration.

It shows **no symbol found**. I expect it should focus to its declaration as specified in the ctags file. Thanks for reading. Awesome editor, hope to learn more

**Other issue**:

Instead of right-click + go to declaration, I press "ctrl+alt+down" to go to declaration, this time, editor hangs.

I see atom-process through 'top' command, its doing 100% CPU usage. I finally need to kill the process.

My .ctags file is ~11MB.

Comment: What exactly does not work mean? What did you expect to happen and what did happen ? What exactly did you do?

Were your ctags generated? Is there any error in developer toolbar?

Comment: @AtomTips any thoughts ?

Comment: @evenCurios might be best to create issue in atom ctags repo.